# Extjs: How to remove cloned items from a form

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a form which I can add multiple fieldsets to it with cloneConfig. The problem is that when I want to create a new form, it will be created with all previously added fieldsets but I need a new form with only one single fieldset. 
How can I do this?

// add fieldset

```
doAddFieldset: function(thisbutton) {
    var fielset = me.getTagFormFieldset().cloneConfig({
        itemId: 's' + (formItemsCount + 1),
    });
    me.getTagForm().add(formItemsCount, fielset);
}
```

// add new Tag

```
doAddTag: function() { 
  var newRec =  Ext.create('MYAPP.model.Tag');
  me.getTagForm().loadRecord(newRec);
}
```

Comment: How do you create the second instance of the form?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to create a new instance of a form, I have a reference and selector for the form and use the getter to that form, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Well, you supposedly have class of the form so you create a new instance with `Ext.create('FormClassName')`

Comment: I get an error when trying to create instance of my form. [E] Ext.AbstractManager.register(): Registering duplicate id "tagformid-legendTitle" with this manager

Comment: Do you use ids on components? NEVER use them, you only call for troubles if you do.

Comment: I'm changing fieldsets itemId to clone them in that form

Comment: Still, the error is "registering duplicate id". Find why and fix it.

Comment: Thank you Saki. I'll try to fix it. But is there any other way to create a new instance of the form?

Comment: I found the problem, I was using id in one of the components in my form.